# How to handle facet filtering and corresponding aggregation counts?

Tags: elasticsearch

Good day to all. The question concerns faceted search.

Suppose there are 2 filters:

2.1 Categories
Freight (1765)
Cars (1566)
Any other (8675)

2.2 Colors
Red (5689)
Green (156)
Blue (3599)
Yellow (2562)

As we see in front of each filter, it is indicated how many elements are individually stored in elastic.
Put a tick in front of the "freight".

Behavior now:

2.1 Categories
Freight (1765)
Cars (0)
Any more (0)

2.2 Colors
Red (red freight number)
Green (number of green freight)
Blue (number of blue freight)
Yellow (number of yellow freight)

You need this behavior:

2.1 Categories
Freight (1765)
Cars (1566)
Any other (8675)

2.2 Colors
Red (red freight number)
Green (number of green freight)
Blue (number of blue freight)
Yellow (number of yellow freight)

That is, that the filter on a specific field does not affect its aggregation, but affects all others. How can this be implemented optimized? Now implemented for x requests to elastic, and x is equal to the number of filters

Best wishes

Comment: Has my answer helped?

Comment: Thanks you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the initial query is `match_all`, the query for

> 2.1 Categories Freight (1765) Cars (1566) Any other (8675)
>
> 2.2 Colors Red (5689) Green (156) Blue (3599) Yellow (2562)

will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "CATEGORIES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      }
    },
    "COLORS": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When **`Freight`** is selected what is expected is explained step by step as below:

**1. Filter the records**

This can be achieved using terms query on `category` field. Now if this query is applied before aggregation, it results into the problem mentioned in the question. The `CATEGORIES` facet will have count against `Frieght` and other counts will be zero. Though the `COLORS` facet will have expected counts. To solve this we can make use of [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html). This will make sure that filtering of records is done after preparing aggregations.

This is how it will work:

**Step 1:** match_all(original query)

**Step 2:** prepare aggregations

**Step 3:** apply the filter (the expected search result)

By the above we will achieve correct filtered results and expected count `CATEGORIES` facet, but the counts in `COLORS` are still same which were expected to reduce according to the selection in the `CATEGORIES` facet. The next step fixes this.

**2. Counts of other facets to be changed accordingly**

To deal with this we will use filter aggregation along with the actual aggregation. We will apply the post_filter in each of the remaining aggregations where the counts should be effected i.e. all aggregations other than `CATEGORIES` which in our case is only `COLORS`.

Combining the above two steps the query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "CATEGORIES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      }
    },
    "COLORS": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "category": [
            "Freight"
          ]
        },
        "aggs": {
          "COLORS": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "color"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "post_filter": {
      "terms": {
        "category": [
          "Freight"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```