# Elasticsearch Filter over dynamic nested fields with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have products with dynamic attributes (filters). I need to get dynamically counts for each value for the filter according to the search query.

I have following mapping for products index:

```
{  
   "products":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "properties":{  
            ...
            "dynamicFilters":{  
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{  
                  "name":{  
                     "type":"keyword"
                  },
                  "value":{  
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And following aggregation request:

```
'size': 0,
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': {
            'match': {
                'category': 'Notebooks'
            }
        },
        'filter': {
            {'nested': {
                'path': 'dynamicFilters',
                'query': {
                    'bool': {
                        'filter': {
                            {'term': {'dynamicFilters.name': 'processor'}},
                            {'terms': {'dynamicFilters.value': {'Ryzen 7'}}},
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
},

'aggs': {
    //'dynamicFilters': {
        //'global': {},   <-- global type commented here
        //'aggs': {
            'dynamicFilters': {
                'nested': {
                    'path': 'dynamicFilters',
                },
                'aggs': {
                    'name': {
                        'terms': {
                            'field': dynamicFilters.name',
                            'size': 20
                        },
                        'aggs': {
                            'value': {
                                'terms': {
                                    'field': 'dynamicFilters.value',
                                    'size': 20
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
        //}
    //}
},
```

The problem is when in the search query will be enabled filter, for instance, "proccesor" with value "Ryzen 7" - in response won't be aggregation for all "processor" values, except "Ryzen 7".

I've tried to make this work with `global type`, but in this case aggs stops working with search query and return all existing counts for values.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: These two answers might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568560/ignore-match-clause-from-query-in-aggregation/55570158#55570158 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376813/how-to-handle-facet-filtering-and-corresponding-aggregation-counts/55378117#55378117

Comment: @Nishant Saini Fields in those questions are not dynamic. This is the key point of my question.